# Python equivalent of MATLABs fopen(filename,'rb',machinetype)

Tags: python, matlab, file

Python provides a way to open a binary file using,

```
open(filename, 'rb')
```

However in Matlab one can also specify machinetype as,

```
fopen(filename, 'rb', machinetype)
```

So I am looking for a way to specify Machinetype(Intel/Motorola) in python too.

Comment: And why do you want that? What difference does that make?

Comment: @AnandSKumar: I might be related to endianess (how bytes are ordered in a multibyte value). Though I don't see how it might be relevant for a byte-oriented interface such as `open(f, 'rb')`. I assume the bit-endianess is the same.

Comment: For machines like Intel and Motorola it defines the order in which data is stored from LSB to MSB or MSB to LSB.

Comment: I think i can use sys.byteorder to check little or big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python this is handled when reading the file, not when opening the file.

Once you open a binary file, you need to read it into some data structure.  Two common ways to do this are with `struct.unpack` and `numpy.fromfile`, both of which allow you set the endianness on per-item basis.  `struct.unpack` reads a given sequence of numbers and/or characters once, while `numpy.fromfile` reads it over and over again and puts the result in an array.

In both cases, putting a `'>'` at the beginning of the type string makes it big-endian while putting `'<'` makes it little-endian.  So for example `'>d'` would be read as a little-endian double in both cases.

This allows you to read files with multiple byte orders in the same file.